# Laravel or Lumen JWT remove default claims

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen, json-web-token

I'm using Tymon's JWTAuth to connect the app to the api in stateless manner thru tokens. But the problem is that when I decode the token, on the payload data, the `iss` value is the API url itself.

How to change the value remove the key from being passed on to the token?

Here's the decoded value of the token (I just edited the value here for example purposes)

```
{
  "iss": "http://localhost.com/api/",
  "iat": 1111111111,
  "exp": 2222222222,
  "nbf": 3333333333,
  "jti": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "sub": 1234,
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "bob"
}
```

I am able to add custom claims but unable to remove the `iss` key.

```
$token = $jwt->attempt($request->only(['username', 'password']));

$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];
$payload = $jwtFactory->customClaims($customClaims)->make(true);
$token = $jwt->encode($payload);

if ($token === false) {
     echo 'invalid credentials';
} else {
     echo 'valid user';
}
```

I even tried:
`$jwtFactory->iss('http://example.com')->foo(['lol'])->make();`

and only the `foo` key or rather the "custom claims" values are being change but not the default claims. But as stated on the [documentation](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens), the default claims value could be changed when set.

Comment: have you removed from required_claims array of jwt config?

Comment: @JigarShah yes I did and it still includes the default claims.

Comment: yes it will as per defaultClaims in PayloadFactory

Comment: @JigarShah yeah, but is there any way not to include those? Or even just set the value of `iss` to something else instead of the request url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to over write the value of the default claims by setting custom claims in which the values of the custom claims are the default claims.

```
$customClaims = ['iss' => 'xxx', 'baz' => 'bob'];
$payload = $jwtFactory->customClaims($customClaims)->make();
```

With this, the value of `iss` (default claims) is now `xxx`. This seems weird as on the [documentation](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens), it has a different way of over writting default claims which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for setting the iss value to null or anything else you may need to modify the `iss()`

```
public function iss()
    {
        return NULL;
        // return $this->request->url();
    }
```

after that you will get the decoded token like

```
array:6 [
  "sub" => 4
  "iss" => null // I have set value to null
  "iat" => 1497603439
  "exp" => 1497963439
  "nbf" => 1497603439
  "jti" => "O6zdDsWKt3X7hszh"
]
```

EDIT

can you please try with this:

```
if ( !$token = JWTAuth::attempt( $credentials, array( 'iss' => NULL ) ) )
```

I have tested with this, its working for me. Also for this we do not need to make changes in package file

Hope that works

Comment: Yeah, tried that and it worked but I think this is not the best way to do it as we are directly modifying it. Any way to override it by not touching the code base?